# Difference between stress test and breakpoint test

Tags: testing, performance-testing

I was looking for the verbal explanations of different performance testing types and saw a new one called "breakpoint test". Its explanation seemed very similar to stress testing for me. So what is the difference, or is there any difference?

> Stress Test: A verification on the system performance during extremely
> high load which is way above the peak load
>
> Breakpoint Test: This test determines the point of system failure by
> gradually increasing the number of simulated concurrent users.

As far as I know, we increase the load gradually while performing stress test too. So what is the difference between this two type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the workload point of view the approach is exactly the same, my understanding is:

- [Stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) is about finding the first bottleneck, it's normally applied before deployment or even at early stages of development (see [shift-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-left_testing) concept)
- [Breakpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Breakpoint_testing) (sometimes also called Capacity) test is about checking how much load the overall integrated environment can handle without issues and what is the slowest component which is a subject for scaling up/optimization.

More information:

- [Software Performance Testing Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Testing_types)
- [Performance Testing vs. Load Testing vs. Stress Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing)
- [What Is Performance Testing: Reviewing Load, Stress, & Capacity Testing](https://www.apica.io/blog/load-testing-vs-stress-testing-vs-capacity-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

Stress testing vs Breakpoint test:

Stress Testing is like load testing but we keep on increasing the load on the server till the time it crash down. The aim of stress testing is to test the insane limits of an application. Stress testing starts of the same as load testing, e.g. gradually increasing load on the servers, the process is repeated till the time the load is reached to the unexpected limits.

But the breakpoint testing , breakpoint is a location in the script or keyword test where you want the script or test to pause during the execution. Once the execution is paused you can check the state of the test ,its output and its variables.

In stress testing we increase the load by gradually increasing the users to check what is the limit of the application and at which load does the app crash , but in the breakpoint testing we already set a breakpoint and check how does the application responds at the set breakpoint , which helps the developer/tester to understand the capability of the application to take load to a specific point.